# String.format alternative on CodenameOne

Tags: java, cross-platform, codenameone

I'm trying to port a Java-based library to CodenameOne in order to use it in a cross-platform project but it uses a lot of Java standard APIs that I cannot find in CodenameOne, first of all `String.format`.

I have read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875676/error-using-split-method-in-codenameone) and I understood there are a few utility libraries which implement what's missing in base classes.
Is there a library class which implements `String.format`?

As an example, I need to do something like `String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hh, mm, ss);`

Comment: Looks like there is no alternative way, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681724/alternative-methods-in-codenameone

Comment: I was reading the very same page. I understand what Shai says about multi-platform support but formatting strings this way is something really mainstream that I don't think has dependencies on the architecture

Answer (score 0):

You can use `com.codename1.l10n.SimpleDateFormat` to format time although personally I just use utility Java code to format as it's simpler. With `Date` we get into the timezone complexities and that's a pain in the neck.

I just usually do:

```
public static String twoDigits(int v) {
    return v < 10 ? "0" + v : "" + v;
}
```

Then:

```
String t = twoDigits(hh) + ":" + twoDigits(mm) + ":" + twoDigits(ss);
```

Notice that this code is more efficient than the `Format` code. The `Format` call needs to parse the formatting then generate the resulting string which is a costly step. Probably won't be noticeable for most cases though.

The main problem we have with `String.format()` is it's presence in `String`. Since String is a core part of the implementation a complex method like that will add weight to every application regardless of need. Also implementing a method like that with so many nuances would mean things would work differently on the simulator than on the device. So it's highly unlikely that we'll ever add that method.

In fact on JavaSE that method is really just a form of `MessageFormat` which is something we could add in the codename1 l10n package. Incompatibility wouldn't be a problem and neither would size/complexity. This is something you can implement yourself and even submit as a pull request if you so desire. You can base your implementation on the Apache licensed harmony project sources or you can build a clean room implementation (which I often found to be easier).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Shai. That's not enough for me, since there are a looooooot of occurrences of this method in the library I need to port (the one I pointed out was just one of like a thousand examples). I just don't feel like replacing each of them with a different method tailored exactly for the occasion (this time is SimpleDateFormat, another time something else) while Java offered a single method for everything.

Comment: Also, imagine I have something like `String.format("2 digits something %2.2d", n)`, how can I achieve the `%2.2.d` thing without using `String.format`?

Comment: There is a digit count format method in the `L10NManager`. See my revised answer covering the problems in `String.format` and discussing an alternative that's closer to what you are looking for